# how to add background color using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to add the background color to the table element.

[image]

```
jq("[class=detailro]").each(function (index) {
var thisAttr = jq(this).attr("pdmqa");
if (thisAttr == "customer.organization.name"){
thisAttr = jq(this).html();
jq(this).css({"background":"#000"});
console.log(thisAttr.trim());}

});
```

1. how to add inline style property to html
2. How can add css property to the element

i want to achieve to change the back ground color of the th element.

thanks

Comment: use `$("body").css("background", "#000");`

Comment: I want to update the background color of the field which is highlighted  in the image. I believe body selector is for full page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this
`$('#df_0_2').css('background', '#000');`
**EDIT**
If you want to target the `customer.organization.name` you can do this

```
$this = $("td[pdmqa='customer.organization.name']");   
$this.css('background', '#000');
```

Hope this help.
SYA :)

Comment: If i add a new field to the form the ID values will get changed, is there any other option.

Comment: Just edited please try the proposed one. Hope this help. SYA :)